# How do I forcibly stop the X server?

Tags: xorg

I am new bie to Ubuntu. I am using Ubuntu 11.10  when I tried to forcibly kill the X server from my process it again starts
and prompts me a login screen how this is happening.

Please help me:

```
vj        2383   908  0 15:01 tty2     00:00:00 -bash
root      3054     1  0 15:04 ?        00:00:00 lightdm
root      4395  3054 14 15:12 tty7     00:21:50 /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -noliste
vj        4498     1  0 15:12 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
vj        4508  3054  0 15:12 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/gnome-session --session=ubuntu

Kill 4395
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The X server is being started by the display manager service, which gets restarted automatically when needed.  `sudo service lightdm stop; sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` to stop it immediately and then configure whether it should be run in the future.

Comment: thanks geekosaur,So lightdm is responsible for Restarting my x continously, So how can I add my my own application to this light dm to start along with X so that it restarts when i forcibly kills my application. an when i tried sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm it is giving me following warnings dpkg-maintscript-helper: warning: environment variable DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_NAME missing
dpkg-maintscript-helper: warning: environment variable DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE missing, please help me.